# how to return return values based on another columns values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the DF:

```
  col1|  col2|
   "a"| "stg"|
   "b"| "etc"|
   "a"| "xyz"|
   "b"| "wha"|
```

And I need the next output:

```
  col1|  col2|   col3|
   "a"| "stg"|"stg:1"|
   "b"| "etc"|"etc:2"|
   "a"| "xyz"|"xyz:1"|
   "b"| "wha"|"wha:2"|
```

So basically I have two columns with only string as variables What i need is third column, which examines col1. If it is an 'a' it returns col2.value + ':1' and if a b it return col2.value + ':2' as one single string
I tried to write a function where

```
def return_stg(x):
    if df[df[col2] == x][col1] == "a":
        return x + ':1'
    if df[df[col2] == x][col1] == "b":
        return x + ':2'
df[col3] = df[col2].apply(return_stg)
```

but it throws a
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

but if I check it by typing only df[df[col2] == "stg"][col1] == "a" it returns a True, so I don't see how it is ambiguous

basically I need that go for every row, check the value in col1, if it is an 'a', return the value from col2 concatenated with string ':1' and etc

Comment: So you need loop slow solution with `apply` ?

Comment: I ask because a bit surprised, what is reason for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One solution:**

```
df["col3"] = np.where(df["col1"] == "a", df["col2"] + ':1', df["col2"] + ':2')
```

**Output:**

```
 col1   col2     col3
0   a    stg    stg:1
1   b    etc    etc:2
2   a    xyz    xyz:1
3   b    wha    wha:2
```

---

**First answer, slower (see comments) :**

In the code you propose, inside the function `return_stg()`, you refer to the complete dataset `df` instead of the current row  `x` (so you are comparing a dataset to a single value). This is what throws the `ValueError`. I would correct it like this:

```
def return_stg(x):
    if x["col1"] == "a":
        return x["col2"] + ':1'
    else:
        return x["col2"] + ':2'
df["col3"] = df.apply(return_stg, axis=1)
```

You can write it in one line:

```
df["col3"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["col2"] + ':1' if x["col1"] == "a" else x["col2"] + ':2', axis=1)
```

Comment: This solution is really bad, unfortunately, because use `apply` what are loops under the hood. Always is necessary avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for noticing and for the link, I edited my answer.

Comment: What is not working with `np.where()` ? (refering to your old comments)

Comment: ya, `np.where` is best alternative for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is best use no loop solution, so you need avoid `apply` (loops under the hoods) or `for`s with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['col1'] == "a"
m2 = df['col1'] == "b"

df['col3'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df['col2'] + ':1', df['col2'] + ':2'], df['col2'])

print (df)
  col1 col2   col3
0    a  stg  stg:1
1    b  etc  etc:2
2    a  xyz  xyz:1
3    b  wha  wha:2
```

If need more dynamic solution it means first unique value of `col1` is `1`, second is `2`, third is `3` use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['col1'])[0], index=df.index).add(1).astype(str)
df['col3'] = df['col2'] + ':' + s
print (df)
  col1 col2   col3
0    a  stg  stg:1
1    b  etc  etc:2
2    a  xyz  xyz:1
3    b  wha  wha:2
```